# Database connection error - not due to wp-config.php - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, database-connection, digital-ocean

I am new to WordPress. I have developed a website and uploaded it. 
The issue I am facing is now that sometimes my site opens perfectly but sometimes it shows an error "ERROR ESTABLISHING A DATABASE CONNECTION".

I have googled and everyone is saying that please check `wp-config.php` file, But my concerns is here that if there is a problem with this file, the site will not open at all. After doing some research, I came to know that there may be some issues with the hosting server usage, but When i checked, there is nothing to worry.
I don't know why its happening, But anyone here any idea ?

Here is my website [link](http://www.daewoo.com.pk/)

and here are some images about the memory and CPU usage for the server(digital ocean 1GB droplet).
[image: CPU and MEMORY usage][image: Bandwidth Usage]

Comment: Try checking your Apache error log. It should be `/var/log/apache2/error.log` by default on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your MySQL stops working due to low memory(1GB RAM). You may try following to resolve this issue.

1. Increase RAM
2. Try to optimize your site. Check your website performance score here https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.daewoo.com.pk/vqXWl2I7 . Use wordpress caching plugin to improve performance.
3. Try to optimize Mysql configuration. See this http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html
4. Check Mysql error log and apache error log for exact issue.